# Java- determine which radio button selected

Tags: java, radio-button

I am dynamically filling a table which contains a `radio button` in each row. How can I go about determining in which row the `radio button` has been selected using `Java`?

```
<form action='ReceptionManagerController' method='POST'>
        <table >
            <tr style="text-align:center">
                     <th>Check-In</th>
                     <th>Check-Out</th>
                     <th>Type</th>
                     <th>Assign Room?</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach var="item" items="${unassignedBookings}">
                <tr>
                    <td>${item.checkIn}</td>
                    <td>${item.checkOut}</td>
                    <td>${item.size}</td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="checked"></td>    
                    <td><input type="hidden" name="id${count}"></td>    
                    <td><input type="hidden" name="checkIn${count}" value="${item.checkIn}"></td>   
                    <td><input type="hidden" name="checkOut${count}" value="${item.checkOut}"></td>     
                    <td><input type="hidden" name="type${count}" value="${item.size}"></td> 
                    <c:set var="count" value="${count + 1}" scope="page"/>  
                </tr>                       
            </c:forEach>


        </table>

        <input  type="submit" name="action" value="Assign Booking"/>
    </form>
```

If I give each `radio button` the same name, then only one can be selected at a time. However, this stops me from determining uniquely which button has been pressed.

Any suggestions?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Shouldn't your radiobuttons be added to a toggle group of some kind? I'm not familiar with this syntax of the code you provided but if there is a possibility to add them to the toggle group, you can get the selected item from that toggle group

Comment: You can use the same name for the radio buttons and apply a check on the value for the radio button. That way you can select only one radio button at a time and uniquely identify the radio button using its value.

Comment: Using spring mvc or struts?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem last year while working on a struts 1.3 based web application. You can refer to the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265501/how-to-update-and-read-radio-button-choice-valueone-for-each-row-in-arraylist) link. I hope it will help you. If still its not clear to you, let me put some try on it.
You can take an ArrayList of your bean type(Using Generics) having the setter and  getter for it and keep the appropriate values for all the bean objects and add all those objects one by one in your ArrayList. After that iterate the ArrayList in your JSP to display the properties along with radio button. Rest of all is explained in given link.
Note: Your bean class must have a property with proper getter/setter for the radio button.

Answer (score 0):

By the form that I can see, Check-Box seems to be appropriate choice rather than Radio Button. As far as capturing the selection is concerned, you can follow same strategy that you are doing for rest of the form elements, suffix count value to radio-Button or check-box to give them uniqueness.